# NameError: name 'idf_text' is not defined

Tags: python

Why I have defined idf_text, but still report an error？

Error:
[image]

The code like this：

```py
def idf_text(doc):
    subject_id,text = doc[0][0],doc[1][0]   
    return subject_id,text


split_data = sorted(map(idf_text,c))
split_data = pd.DataFrame(split_data)
type(split_data)  
data = split_data[1]
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: try putting the `def idf_text(doc)` to be in the same line as your `split_data`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Is indentation correct?

Comment: Try the code again after my edit.

Comment: could you supply a `c` argument example?